# Adding a custom connector in Apache Flink/Ververica CE

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

Apache Flink/Ververica Community Edition - Question

I am trying to add a custom connector to ververica community edition and keeps giving me the following error:
"The jar contains multiple connector. Please choose one.", it doesn't allow me to choose more jars.  I am testing with the following repo generated custom connectors: https://github.com/deadwind4/slink/tree/master/connector-es6

My specific question is there anything specific missing from this repo that we should add to signal ververica about a custom record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is misleading, and the issue is that no connector was found.

This is because Ververica Platform only supports the [new connector interfaces](https://docs.ververica.com/user_guide/sql_development/connectors.html#developing-a-custom-connector-or-format).
Factory discovery also requires an entry in `META-INF/services`, which appears to be missing.

For examples of connectors that implement these interfaces, see https://github.com/Airblader/flink-connector-imap and https://github.com/knaufk/flink-faker.

(This was answered on the mailing list by Ingo Bürk; I've paraphrased his response.)

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't seen the SO question at first. :-)